# ServiceStack with AngularJS: JSON Vulnerability Protection and XSRF

Tags: angularjs, servicestack

The AngularJS documentation provides some recommendation to protect a web side against JSON Vulnerability and XSRF Attacks (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http section "Security Considerations").

How can I configure the JSON serialize to prefix my JSON?
What is the best way to get a verifiable value for the "X-XSRF-TOKEN" token value and how to validate that for each request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `GlobalResponseFilter` to prefix your JSON with:

```
this.GlobalResponseFilters.Add((req, res, dto) =>
{
    if (req.ResponseContentType.MatchesContentType(MimeTypes.Json) 
        && !(dto is IHttpResult))
    {
        res.Write(")]}',\n");
    }
});
```

Which will write the recommended prefix before the serialized JSON response.

This will protect against JS `Array` vulnerability, an alternative approach would be to wrap array responses in a DTO, e.g:

```
return new Response { Results = Db.Select<Poco>() };
```

Which would serialize as a JSON object avoids the JS Array vulnerability.

I prefer returning object responses since it doesn't limit your JSON services to only work with appropriately configured JS Apps and object responses are more forward-compatible/future-proofed as you can later modify the service to return multiple return types without breaking compatibility with existing clients.

Any random string should make a good token, e.g. hex-encoded random bytes or just a new Guid.

Comment: Regarding to the XSRF recomandation: I need to create the "XSRF-TOKEN" cookie, so that is accessable for Angular. By default SS enforces "HttpOnly" cookies, even if I create a cookie with "HttpOnly"=false. When setting the AllowNonHttpOnlyCookies option to true, Angular can access that cookie and sends the "X-XSRF-TOKEN" - all fine. But now also the "ss-id" cookie is suddenly a none "HttOnly" cookie!? Correct me if I am wrong, but that ss-id should allwayas be a "HttpOnly" cookie. No JS should ever be able to mess with the sessionId, I think that also holds true for the ss-pid cookie.